# django: how to calculate percentile of each value

Tags: django

I have a model

```
class TestResults(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    score = models.FloatField()
```

Now how to add percentile column using annotate

the procedure for calculating percentile of each value

```
Percentile = (number of values below score) ÷ (total number of scores) x 100
```

I know we can use annotate

```
from django.db.models import F
total = TestResults.objects.all().count()
TestResults.objects.annotate(...)  <-- here how to get number of values below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) and the [`PercentRank` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#percentrank) function to calculate the percentile:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions import PercentRank


results = TestResults.objects.annotate(
    percentile=Window(
        expression=PercentRank(),
        order_by=F('score').asc()
    ) * 100
)

for result in results:
    print(result.name, result.score, result.percentile)
```